# How to repair 33 mb capacity on my WD10EZEX?

Tags: windows, hard-drive

My hard drive has a factory capacity of 1 TB (WD10EZEX-21M). However, one day (I do not know the details), I found that in Windows it has a capacity of 33 MB.

I booted into Linux. In gparted, the capacity of my disk is displayed correctly and I was able to break it into sections of 500 GB. However, after loading into windows, I still see a volume of 33 MB.

In Linux, I tried to check for hidden partitions: the `hdparm -N /dev/sda` command, here's the result:

```
/dev/sda:
 max sectors = 1953525168/1953525168, HPA is disabled
```

Also I tried to use the command - the restaurant:

```
hdparm --yes-i-know-what-i-am-doing --dco-restore/dev/sda
```

The answer is:

```
/dev/sda:
 issuing DCO restore command
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb []: 70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 40 00 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

What can i do with this hdd? How to repair it?

upd:

```
DISKPART> list disk

  Диск ###  Состояние      Размер   Свободно Дин  GPT
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Диск 0    В сети           31 Mбайт    30 Mбайт
  Диск 1    В сети          465 Gбайт  1024 Kбайт        *

DISKPART> list volume

  Том    ###  Имя  Метка        ФС     Тип         Размер   Состояние  Сведения
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
     Том 0     C                NTFS   Раздел       465 Gб  Исправен   Загрузоч
     Том 1         Восстановит  NTFS   Раздел       450 Mб  Исправен   Скрытый
     Том 2                      FAT32  Раздел       100 Mб  Исправен   Системны
```

One IMPORTANT THING! If i just reboot computer, without full shutdown, capacity not decreases (in windows too).

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I found this solution:

1. Load from USB in Linux
2. Run fdisk, clear your bad hdd and make new
   **GPT** partition with NTFS
3. Reload to Windows
4. In Administrating->Computer management (in Russian is "Управление
   компьютером")->Disk management choose your new partition (it is in
   RAW format) and delete it. After this action, partition WILL
   DISAPPEAR, but it's only for windows.
5. Reload to Linux again and input command:

   ```
   hdparm -N /dev/sdd - where /dev/sdd is your drive
   ```

   You will see:

   ```
   /dev/sdd:
       max sectors   = 586070255/586072368, HPA is enabled,
   ```

   where 586072368 - full capacity of your drive
6. hdparm -N p586072368 /dev/sdd, where 586072368- full capacity of your drive.

The letter 'p' is required for the settings to be saved in the flash hard disk (that is, after the power is turned off, they are preserved). You can change the parameter with the 'p' key **only once per session** of the hard disk (session - the time interval between on and off). After changing the parameter, you must turn off and turn on the hard drive (in fact - the computer).

After it, i reloaded in windows and found that my drive has normal state with full capacity.